# About Query methods Conditions in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hash way works just fine:

```
drummers = Drummer.where(:gender => true)

=> [#<Drummer id: 1, first_name: "Bernard", middle_name: nil, second_name: "Purdie", nick_name: "Pretty Purdie", gender: true, created_at: "2010-12-05 02:47:56", updated_at: "2010-12-05 02:50:42">]
```

But the same thing in String way:

```
drummers = Drummer.where("gender = true")
```

I got below error:
`A`ctiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: TRUE: SELECT     "drummers".* FROM       "drummers"  WHERE     (gender = TRUE)

anybody could tell mewhy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sqlite error, not rails. When you say `gender = true`, it's looking for a column that is named `true`. Sqlite does not have booleans, so the correct way to do this is `Drummer.where("gender = 1")`.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using strings where possible in your Arel queries.

If you're joining a table that also contains a field named 'gender' then this will break, because it's ambiguous. Using `where(:gender => true)` will automatically be namespaced for you, so that won't happen.

As your example shows, using strings also can create portability problems, if you're using a feature that your backend doesn't support.

I've been using a plugin called [MetaWhere](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/) to augment ARel's syntax, making strings less necessary.